# How to pass a NSMutableArray including NSManagedObjects to another view controller?

Tags: objective-c, core-data, uiviewcontroller, nspredicate, nscoding

I embedded 'Core Data' into my app. I use a predicate and fetch the result. I use a mutableArray called "fetchedObjects" to get the (predicated and then fetched) result. Now I need to pass this result to another view controller. How can I do that?

1.First thing I tried is using 'NSCoding' but it didn't work out. I think Core Data doesn't comply with NSCoding, am I right?

If I can use 'NSCoding', how do I do it? I tried to save and then load the fetchedObjects but it didn't work out.

2.Off course I can define a pointer using

```
"product = [[Product alloc] initWithEntity:entity insertIntoManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];"
```

but how can I get just the "fetchedObjects" mutableArray but not all the objects?

3.Do you know a better way to pass a NSMutableArray having NSManagedObjects in it? and how can we pass the NSManagedObjects to the other view controllers, only in the context?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an NSNotification.

Say View Controller A fetches the results, and View Controller B needs them.

in VCA:

```
NSArray *data = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
 postNotificationName:@"newFetchedDataNotification"
               object:nil
             userInfo:@{@"data": data}];
```

in VCB:

in viewWillAppear, start listening for the notification:

```
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                          selector:@selector(processData)
                                              name:@"newFetchedDataNotification"
                                            object:nil];
```

and add a method:

```
- (void)processData:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    NSArray *data = [notification.userInfo objectForKey:@"succeeded"]
}
```

And don't forget to unregister for notifications in viewWillDisappear:

```
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
```

I still think the preferred way is using an NSFetchedResultsController to do a first fetch and be notified when objects change. Take a look at this tutorial:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/999/core-data-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-use-nsfetchedresultscontroller

PS: NSManagedObjects are just like any other objects, no need to use encoding. You need to be careful when modifying and saving them though!

Comment: Thanks! I checked the NSFetchedResultsController, it seems to be the best way. I was planning to use ObjectID and unique url but now I change my architecture to use NSFetchedResultsController. The problem here is, I  fetch the objects in a VC and I need to display them in a tableview in another VC. I checked the documentation but couldn't find what to do. Can you please briefly explain how I can set NSFetchedResultsController in a VC and use it in another one? Thanks

Comment: The beauty with the NSFetchedResultsController is that you don't need to worry about the data changing. You set it up in your table view's data source and delegate, specifying which objects it should fetch and on which MOC to listen. Any changes to objects that are relevant to the fetch will notify your FetchedResultsController which will automatically execute a fetch. All of this is very well explained in the tutorial in the link!
PS: If the answer helped, don't forget to accept it with the green checkmark below the votes on the left.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than passing the managed objects directly, if all them are already saved I would pass the ObjectID or the unique url, and have the receiver retrieve them from the store.

Retrieving is fast, and also will avoid many problem that may occur with concurrency.

If the receiving controller just need to display data, I would also think about retrieving just the properties you need with an NSDictionary result type, and pass the resulting array to the controller. But of course, I don't know anything about your design.

**UPDATE**

If I understood correctly your comment, the big advantage of NSFRC is the bunch of delegate methods it brings with it. If you made your UIViewController the delegate of your NSFRC which is `NSFetchedResultsControlerDelegate` then the fetched controller itself will invoke your view controllers implemented delegate methods, as soon as there's a change in the model. Then within this methods you have to refresh your table view.
The view is not going to be refreshed by itself.

The difference is that if your UITableView datasource is just an array of managed objects, you would need to build by yourself all the logic to react to model change, recognize which cell need to be refreshed, then decide if it deleted/updated/moved etc.. if you think about it, it is quite a few logic to be implemented, and will not be as efficient as the NSFRC is which is already customized for this purpose.

Also, by reading the rest of your comment, you cannot pass a NSFetchedResultsController, well I suppose you can, but it is useless, the NSFRC is meant to be created and used in the UIViewController on screen. The NSFRC is instantiated with few parameters, one of them is a `NSFetchRequest`, so you have to customize your request to retrieve the objects you need.

P.S.
Sorry, at the moment I am behind a company firewall which is blocking many sites (including Apple docs), therefore I cannot give you any links.

Comment: Thanks Leonardo! Using ObjectID and unique url is the way to go in my architecture but I decided to use NSFetchedResultsController, it seems to be a more hassle-free way, so I will change my architecture. But I need to ask you another question, please help me; if I use ObjectID or unique url, I should use refresh controller to refresh the data I display in tableview but if I use NSFetchedResultsController I don't need to use refresh controller as it will refresh asynchronously? Is this the difference between them? I couldn't find an answer to my question through Google. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In simple way ,

**VC2.h**

```
@property (strong) NSMutableArray *device;
```

**VC2.m**

```
@synthesize device;
```

Now in Your  VC1 from which you want to pass array

```
    VC2 *v2=[VC2 alloc]initWithNibName:@"VC2" bundle:nil];
    v2.device = array;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:v2 animated:YES];
```

or if you are not using Navigationcontroller.

```
[self presentViewController:v2 animated:YES completion:nil];
```